# Permission denied: cannot call non-public or static methods remotely

Tags: c++-cli

in my code there are no "non-public" or "static" methods. All are public.I'm creating a Custom tool class,  but However when I try to invoke a method from this class on the remote object I get stuck with an exception:

Permission denied: cannot call non-public or static methods remotely.
Fails at the following line everytime.

```
   public ref class CustomTool : public Tool 
        {

        public:
            CustomTool():Tool()
            {
            }


        };


                CustomTool ^cs = gcnew CustomTool();

                window->SetTool(cs); // here
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is with the method "*SetTool*" rather than the object "*cs*".

How does *SetTool* looks like?

Comment: actually the  problem was with the method thks :)